# Firebase http route doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have defined the following route in firebase:

```
// ONLY FOR TESTING
exports.findprinters = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log("Finding printers");
  findGooglePrinters();
});
```

I have deployed:

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'company-1234'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (47.21 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: creating function findprinters...
i  functions: updating function quarterly_job...
i  functions: updating function createNewUser...
i  functions: updating function createStripeCharge...
i  functions: updating function createStripeCustomer...
i  functions: updating function addPaymentSource...
i  functions: updating function cleanupUser...
✔  functions[createStripeCharge]: Successful update operation. 
✔  functions[addPaymentSource]: Successful update operation. 
✔  functions[createStripeCustomer]: Successful update operation. 
✔  functions[cleanupUser]: Successful update operation. 
✔  functions[createNewUser]: Successful update operation. 
✔  functions[findprinters]: Successful create operation. 
Function URL (findprinters): https://us-central1-company-1234.cloudfunctions.net/findprinters
✔  functions[quarterly_job]: Successful update operation. 

✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/company-1234/overview
```

[image]

But the route does not seem to be working. I go to `https://company-1234.firebaseapp.com/findprinters` but it doesn't work. The `console.log` does not log `"Finding printers"` like I expect it to. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
https://us-central1-company-1234.cloudfunctions.net/findprinters
```

That URL is the normal public API endpoint or "HTTP-trigger" for that function. If you would use Postman to make a GET request to that URL, you should expect to run your function. (*Or if you visited that URL in your browser, your browser would make a GET request to that URL, and your function should run then too*)

The problem comes when you want to access it from your deployed/hosted website. You need to tell the hosting portion of Firebase to route any traffic for `/findprinters` to your function - your Firebase hosting should **not** try to resolve the `/findprinters` route as a normal HTML page deployed along-side the primary index.html file... instead it should direct any traffic for `/findprinters` to the cloud function `findprinters`

So, you need to tell Firebase to direct any traffic for `/findprinters` to the cloud function, not hosting. You give Firebase commands/configuration in the `firebase.json` file... in this case, under a section named "rewrites" like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",

    // Add the following rewrites section *within* "hosting"
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "/findprinters", "function": "findprinters"
    } ]

  }
}
```

Check out [this documentation link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct_hosting_requests_to_your_function) where it explains all that^^

Once you've done that, redeploy everything, and now you should be able to visit `/findprinters` in your browser and trigger the function. **NOTE** Unless you are using `firebase serve` you should visit the route on the *deployed website*, not localhost. Check out [this link for more details](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#use_firebase_serve_for_https_functions) on `firebase serve`.